# Refactor selective item by highest create date or update date

Tags: c#

I have to check for the Highest Date from CostRepository whether it is create date or edit date then i have to get value in that field. edit date can be null. i don't know how to fix the codesmell.

```
var allCostsInThisPo = CostRepository
                       .GetAll()
                       .WhereInPo(po.po_surr_key);

if (allCostsInThisPo.Any())
{
    var costWithMaxCreatedDate = allCostsInThisPo.OrderByDescending(item => item.create_date).First();
    var allEditedCosts = allCostsInThisPo.Where(item=>item.update_date != null);


    if (allEditedCosts.Any())
    {
        var costWithMaxEditedDate = allEditedCosts.OrderByDescending(item => item.update_date).First();

        if (costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date > costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date)
        {
            history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);
        }
        else
        {
            history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxEditedDate.EditedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date.Value);  
        }

    }
    else
    {
        history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and make LINQ do more, to me it is more readable but it may not be to your style.

```
var allCostsInThisPo = CostRepository
                       .GetAll()
                       .WhereInPo(po.po_surr_key);

if (allCostsInThisPo.Any())
{    
    var costWithMaxCreatedDate = allCostsInThisPo.OrderByDescending(item => item.create_date)
                                                        .Select(c => new { Name = c.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, Date = c.create_date})
                                                        .First();

    // if there is a max edited date greated than the cost created date then this will
    // be populated, otherwise will be null. 
    var costWithMaxEditedDate = allCostsInThisPo.Where(item => item.update_date.HasValue && item.update_date.Value > costWithMaxCreatedDate.Date)
                                                          .OrderByDescending(c => item.update_date.Value)       
                                                          .Select(c => new { Name = c.EditedByUser.user_fullname, Date = c.update_date.Value})                                                                                                  
                                                          .FirstOrDefault();

    var maxCost = costWithMaxEditedDate ?? costWithMaxCreatedDate;

    history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(maxCost.Name, maxCost.Date); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's indent the code properly and remove unnecessary whitespace:

```
var allCostsInThisPo = CostRepository
    .GetAll()
    .WhereInPo(po.po_surr_key);

if (allCostsInThisPo.Any())
{
    var costWithMaxCreatedDate = allCostsInThisPo.OrderByDescending(item => item.create_date).First();
    var allEditedCosts = allCostsInThisPo.Where(item=>item.update_date != null);

    if (allEditedCosts.Any())
    {
        var costWithMaxEditedDate = allEditedCosts.OrderByDescending(item => item.update_date).First();

        if (costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date > costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date)
        {
            history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);
        }
        else
        {
            history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxEditedDate.EditedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date.Value);  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);  
    }
}
```

What the code is actually doing is that it assigns values `history.AllocationInfo` depending on some conditions. The assignement is always using the very long `BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay` called with different arguments. Let's return those arguments instead.

```
private AllocationHistoryInfo RetrieveAllocationHistoryInfo(dynamic allCostsInThisPo)
{
    var costWithMaxCreatedDate = allCostsInThisPo.OrderByDescending(item => item.create_date).First();
    var allEditedCosts = allCostsInThisPo.Where(item=>item.update_date != null);

    if (allEditedCosts.Any())
    {
        var costWithMaxEditedDate = allEditedCosts.OrderByDescending(item => item.update_date).First();

        if (costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date > costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date)
        {
            return new AllocationHistoryInfo(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);
        }
        else
        {
            return new AllocationHistoryInfo(costWithMaxEditedDate.EditedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date.Value);  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return new AllocationHistoryInfo(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);  
    }
}

// Later in code:
var allCostsInThisPo = CostRepository
    .GetAll()
    .WhereInPo(po.po_surr_key);

if (allCostsInThisPo.Any())
{
    var allocationHistoryInfo = this.RetrieveAllocationHistoryInfo(allCostsInThisPo);
    history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(allocationHistoryInfo.Cost, allocationHistoryInfo.CreateDate);
}
```

Given that `return` will stop processing the method, we can now shorten the code like this.

```
private AllocationHistoryInfo RetrieveAllocationHistoryInfo(dynamic allCostsInThisPo)
{
    var costWithMaxCreatedDate = allCostsInThisPo.OrderByDescending(item => item.create_date).First();
    var allEditedCosts = allCostsInThisPo.Where(item=>item.update_date != null);
    if (allEditedCosts.Any())
    {
        var costWithMaxEditedDate = allEditedCosts.OrderByDescending(item => item.update_date).First();
        if (costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date <= costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date)
        {
            return new AllocationHistoryInfo(costWithMaxEditedDate.EditedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxEditedDate.update_date.Value);  
        }
    }

    return new AllocationHistoryInfo(costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser.user_fullname, costWithMaxCreatedDate.create_date);  
}

// Later in code:
var allCostsInThisPo = CostRepository
    .GetAll()
    .WhereInPo(po.po_surr_key);

if (allCostsInThisPo.Any())
{
    var allocationHistoryInfo = this.RetrieveAllocationHistoryInfo(allCostsInThisPo);
    history.AllocationInfo = BuilkConstant.LogHistorySetting.GetAllocationHistoryLogDisplay(allocationHistoryInfo.Cost, allocationHistoryInfo.CreateDate);
}
```

This final version is still difficult to read and understand. Your strong point is to name your variables correctly, so I won't spend too much time trying to rename them. If `EditedByUser` and `CreatedByUser` share the same interface, you can slighly simplify the method by adding a constructor overload to `AllocationHistoryInfo`, taking the interface as a parameter, leading to `costWithMaxEditedDate.EditedByUser` and `costWithMaxCreatedDate.CreatedByUser`, without `user_fullname`. A few minor changes may simplify the code, but not too much.

You may also try to:

- Refactor the single method into several smaller ones,
- Comment the code.

Comment: What do you mean by “indent the code properly”? The change you made to the initialization of `allCostsInThisPo`? I'm not sure that's an improvement.

Comment: Also, why did you decide to use `dynamic`? That's usually a bad idea, unless there is a good reason to use it.

Comment: @svick: by "indent the code properly", I mean what you did in your edit of the question. As for the initialization, I should review it carefully; there may be mistakes in my answer.

Comment: @svick: I used `dynamic` because there is no way to determine the actual type from the piece of code given in the question. So yes, the OP should use the real type instead of `dynamic`.

Comment: Well, that's usually an artifact of people copying code that's inside a method inside a class inside a namespace, so it appears more indented than it has to here, but it's actually okay in the real code.